# LUKS - Detached header - where is encryption key stored?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, dm-crypt

I encrypted a disk using LUKS with detached header. The header was present on a removable disk.

Once the mapped device (under /dev/mapper) was created, I removed the disk containing header. I was able to read-write using that mapped device. Of course, I would need the header again if I close the mapped device.

1. Does the mapper store the encryption parameters somewhere?
2. If yes, how secure is the key stored because it would be decrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure the actual keys are stored in the kernel's keyring, where they're stored safely & isolated from other users. (At least as safe as anything on the computer, a user/process with root access can read anything too).

The mapper knows where the device is & how big it is, and the key. You can see general parameters with `losetup` and `cryptsetup status`, and attempt to see the kernel keyring with `keyctl`.

You don't really need the header again unless you want to add/delete/edit a key. I doubt you'd need the header again to close the device, since "closing" it just forgets the key & stops decrypting it.